# Automate image cutting with python

Tags: python, image-processing, automation, python-imaging-library

I would like to cut an image into 12 equal boxes, because the Instagram mobile app shows a 3x4 table. In resume, I want to automate a Image Cutter to make mosaics at Instagram.
I downloaded [Pillow's library](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow).

This is the code that I have written:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("Koala.jpg")

x,y = img.size  #assign x,y to image's valors
a = round(x/3)  #widht   
b = round(y/4)   #height

img2 = img.crop((0,0,a,b))  #assing variable img2 to the first box    
img2.save("img2.jpg")       #save the first box

img3 = img.crop((a,0,a,b))   #assign variable img3 to the box next to img2    
img3.save("img3.jpg")        #save

img4 = img.crop((2*a,0,a,b)) #same process
img4.save("img4.jpg")
```

I think that would be easy using a loop. Sorry, I'm a noob and this is my first script in python.

Comment: So - just note that nothing in Python requires variable letters to have a single letter. It makes no sense writting `a = round(x/3)  #widht ` to remind you and other people vieing the code  that `a` contains the widthwhen you can simply use `width` and  `height` as variable names themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply use a double `for` loop,

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        img_tmp = img.crop((i*a, j*b, (i+1)*a, (j+1)*b)) 
        img_tmp.save("img_{}_{}.jpg".format(i, j))
```